# Ошибка при запуске проекта после добавления поддержки Maven

Tags: java, javafx, maven

Имеется рабочий проект, решил добавить поддержку Maven в него, после преобразования не хочет запускаться и ругается на JavaFX:

`at com.company.Visual.run(Visual.java:25)` - ссылается на - `Parent panel = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../../../resources/sample.fxml"));`

`at com.company.Visual.start(Visual.java:19)` - ссылается на - `run(primaryStage);`

**Ошибка:**

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:473)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:372)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:941)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:973)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:198)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3246)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3210)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3179)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3152)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3129)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3122)
    at com.company.Visual.run(Visual.java:25)
    at com.company.Visual.start(Visual.java:19)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:919)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$11(PlatformImpl.java:449)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$9(PlatformImpl.java:418)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:417)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:175)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application com.company.Visual
```

**Код запуска:**

```
public class Visual extends Application {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        run(primaryStage);
    }


    public void run(Stage primaryStage) throws  Exception{

        Parent panel = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../../../resources/sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(panel, 700, 550));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

**FXML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.web.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="550.0" prefWidth="700.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.company.Controller">
   <children>
      <WebView fx:id="webView" layoutX="5.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="389.0" prefWidth="591.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="-3.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="4.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="14.0" />
      <TextField fx:id="searchfield" layoutX="276.0" layoutY="201.0" visible="false" />
      <Button fx:id="search" layoutX="308.0" layoutY="271.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#SearchButton" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="85.0" text="поиск" visible="false" />
      <ListView fx:id="viewgroups" layoutX="9.0" layoutY="153.0" prefHeight="308.0" prefWidth="680.0" visible="false" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="8.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="10.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**Controller:**

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {

    private Parent fxmlEdit;
    private FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
    private SelectAlbums selectAlbums;
    private Stage editStage;


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        try {
            run();

            fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("albums.fxml"));
            fxmlEdit = fxmlLoader.load();
            selectAlbums = fxmlLoader.getController();


        }catch (Exception e){}
    }


    public void run() throws  Exception{
       System.out.println("Запуск произведен");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пути к `*.fxml` файлам типа `../../../resources/sample.fxml` необходимо заменить на `/sample.fxml`.

Answer (score 1):

В Maven, в отличии от Ant, код и ресурсы лежат в разных местах. По умолчанию код лежит в директории `src/main/java`, а ресурсы в директории `src/main/resources`. Такое же разделение существует между кодом и ресурсами тестов: `src/test/java` и `src/test/resources`. Судя по всему вы скопировали код и ресурсы вмести.